# VNC viewer not connecting to Mac from Windows

Tags: mac-osx, mac, vnc

I have a VNC server running on a Mac.
When I try to use a VNC viewer, it says "no matching security types".

Is there any other software which can connect to a Mac like RDP?

If iI use screen sharing from another Mac, then it works but not from VNC.

EDIT: I am using:

- Leopard 10.5.7,
- vnc VIEWER 4.1.3,
- nothing installed on Mac,
- On Same LAN,

Comment: Is this the built-in VNC server in OS X? What version of OS X are you running? What VNC viewer are you using? Is this on the same LAN? is there a network device between the two computer like a router or firewall?

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Turn on "Screen Sharing" under preferences on the Mac, go into Advanced, check both boxes, enter a password. -- "Remote Management" will also work, but only with some viewers; if you want to use TightVNC, for example, you need to use Screen Sharing (Remote Management won't work).

Comment: For me it worked only after disabling the firewall. Afterwards I found https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/112046/screen-sharing-suddenly-stopped-working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try TightVNC to connect.  It seems to work when the free edition of RealVNC does not.
http://www.tightvnc.com/

I've also found that the VNC viewer will konk out when connecting to the Mac if the viewer is not running in millions or full color mode.

Comment: I tried it and it says  , server did not offer supported security type

Comment: It also says , no configured security type is supported by 3.3 viewer

Comment: That's because of the version conflict I referred to in my answer.

Comment: I installe VNC enterprise view , finally it got connected but looks weired like only 16 colors or something

Comment: Now TightVNC is also working but the problem is color , TightVNC also shows only 256 colors

Comment: Your suggestion about color mode worked for me. Before enabling the setting  "Always use best color quality" a screen would quickly popup and disappear after entering the password when connecting.

Comment: "No security types supported" can be fixed -- turn off "Remote Management" on the Mac and turn on "Screen Sharing" instead. -- Go to advanced and check both boxes, and enter a password; then it will allow a simple password log on.

Answer (score 8):

A few years later, the "world has changed", so

The free version of RealVNC (v. 6.17.1113, Nov 2017, x64) works smoothly for me. In particular from Windows 7 Professional to OS X Yosemite (10.11) *and* to OS X High Sierra (10.13 w/ latest updates), the "OS X Authentication" that Mac OS builtin VNC requires, with username and password and no tweaks to the VNC server side, posed no problem. These are security types 30 and 35: see https://vncdotool.readthedocs.io/en/0.8.0/rfbproto.html#security

*Although* performance was clearly lacking. It's using ZRLE compression; perhaps JPEG or something else is superior, and perhaps professional RealVNC is optimized.

TightVNC and TigerVNC both fail complaining those are unknown codes.

[And do everything over a VPN for heaven's sake if going through the Internet.]

Answer (score 7):

I ran this command and could get it to work with RealVNC Open/Free edition viewer. Ensure that on the client, the color level is set to Full [Options->Colour & Encoding->Colour Level]

```
sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -activate -configure -access -off -restart -agent -privs -all -allowAccessFor -allUsers -clientopts -setvncpw -vncpw secret -setvnclegacy -vnclegacy yes
```

This method works via the command line (local terminal and remote ssh session too).

Comment: thank you thank you thank you, it made it work and made my day!

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure which VNC server you have running on your Mac, but you can use the built-in one.

Apple menu --> System Preferences --> Sharing --> Screen Sharing

Make sure that its configured for VNC access with a password.  Then try to connect to TCP port 5900 with a VNC client on your PC.

To answer the other question:  VNC is the Mac answer to RDP, actually.  Even the commercial "Apple Remote Desktop" package ultimately uses the VNC protocol.

Comment: I had the same problem and this worked for me. Simply configure a password in the option popup.

Answer (score 5):

Try turning off encryption, works for me for a similar problem.

Comment: For RealVNC: set Encryption to "Prefer On" or "Prefer Off", the default (Server) will give you authentication errors no matter how correct your password is.

Answer (score 1):

From memory you'll need to either use a v3.x viewer or configure the one you have to use the version 3 protocol. How depends on your viewer but it should be covered in its help file or web site.

Answer (score 1):

Any VNC client I've tried works.  On your Mac

1. Go to System Preferences -> Sharing -> Enable Screen Sharing
2. Click the `Computer Settings...` button
3. In the drop-down sheet, check both boxes for `Anyone may request permission to control screen` and `VNC viewers may control screen with password:`
4. Enter a password
5. Click `OK` button
6. Leave system preferences

Once you've done that, be sure **not** to use 256 colors.  Then, when connecting from your other computer you should be prompted for a normal VNC password, followed by the OsX login screen, where you can choose the user you'd like to log in as.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem on El Capitan. TightVNC viewer (version 2.7.10) worked without any problem with Yosemite but failed to connect to Mac after upgrade to El Capitan. Looks like TightVNC 2.7.x does not support VNC protocol used by newer versions of OSX.

I've switched over to [RealVNC](https://www.realvnc.com/) [Viewer](https://www.realvnc.com/download/viewer/) (version 5.3.1) which works without any error.

Comment: Can you get RealVNC work with Sierra? I've been trying to access Sierra from Windows 10 PC without any luck. I keep getting "Timed out" error. Both computers are on the same network and I've turned on Screen Sharing on my Macbook Pro

Answer (score 0):

You can encounter this problem if the server does not have a password configured, or the server is running with integrated authentication and you are using the free VNC viewer. The free VNC viewer does not support some of the newer authentication methods.

Answer (score 0):

If, like me, you have problems to connect to MacOS from *Ubuntu* (I know the question was originally for windows, but this might be useful)

What worked for me was:
Use *[Remmina](https://remmina.org/)*,
use the Vnc Password that was setup on Mac
as Username, *any valid user in the mac* system will do.
Do *not* use 256 bit colors

In my case neither `xtightvǹc` or `tigervnc` could connect from ubuntu 18.04